# Latency and load time issues when delivering content to China and Singapore

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, rds

**Background** - Simply, I'm taking a PHP/MySQL website and trying to resolve latency and slow load time issues in China. I've setup a webserver instance (EC2) in Virginia and Singapore and an RDS in Virginia that replicates to Singapore. Since the AWS RDS replicas can't be written to, for the time being the Singapore EC2 is writing to  the Virginia RDS.

On top of that I have implemented a latency rule using Route 53 that determines which EC2 a client should be delivered to.

[Here's a diagram of my setup, if it helps.](http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/8200169)

**The Issue** - The solution above reduces latency and load times when reading from the database but when writing to the database (from Singapore) the site slows down a bit because, of course, it is writing to a DB in Virginia.

My guess is that I need a master DB in Asia and in Virginia but I do not know how to keep the two masters synchronized.

Comment: Honestly the latency problem related truly related with distance and service providers who between client and server... YOUR CLIENT MAY BE OK, YOUR SERVICE MAY OK, but between them may cause probs

Comment: @user1844933 Thank you for your response. I understand that my problem is due to the distance between the Singapore and Virginia servers. My hope is that you can offer me some insight into how I might resolve the issue. It seems that I may need a dual-master DB setup but I have not been able to find any documentation that is helpful with AWS.

Comment: friend, we can not do anything thing for latency problem, unless change service provider to local.....

Answer (score 0):

RDS does not support multi master, you can set up your own instances to do it, but its not without some challenges. It appears the me that you are going down the route of making your infrastructure complex without analyzing all possible solutions to improve latency.

China is a bit of a unique case. If you are serious about doing business in China, you really need to host directly in the country. Filtering and other restrictions can make it difficult to do business from outside of the country. In this case you would probably manage a China store separate from your other store.

Before investing in a multi-datacenter setup, I would make sure all other low hanging fruit is taken care of in terms of latency.

1. Make sure web application response time is as low as possible. Use opcaches and caching here, tune mysql, use nginx instead of apache with php-fpm. New relic is awesome for profiling. Target latency here depends on the application.
2. Move all static assets to a CDN. If you are using AWS, cloudfront is the way to go.
3. Choose a data center that has the best average latency to most of your customers. If most of your customers are in Asia and the US, US West data center may be better here. (Routing between cities can get interesting, not all routes take the most geographically efficient path. It depends on the agreements between various ISP's)

If you have done all this, and you still want to go down the multi-datacenter path. You will have to set up your own multi-master install of Mysql. This route has possible pitfalls. Latency may present issues with how transactions work.